I have a question about downloading Ubuntu version between LTS and basic one
Why there's only one option to download Ubuntu 24.04 LTS? I remember that there were two options available for download Ubuntu 23.10.1 and Ubuntu LTS 23.04 but now there's an LTS version of Ubuntu

23.10.1 never existed as a valid release i think that was just an ISO respin.  24.04 LTS is the latest supported version, and it JUST came out, so it has no ISO respins or variant respins.

If you mean minimal installation and a full installation, they are both available in the same .iso.

"there were two options available for download Ubuntu 23.10.1 and Ubuntu LTS 23.04" You read it wrong. The options were 23.10.1 and LTS 22.04. The new 24.04 LTS replaces both for 6 months. The separate choices will resume when 24.10 (non-LTS) is released.

Okay, thank you! I thought they deleted an Interim Release haha

Much depends on where you look and your choice over search conditions.
Ubuntu is available to download from https://releases.ubuntu.com/ going back as far as version 14.04 in this resource from Ubuntu.
